# ошибка в procfile heroku

Tags: java, maven, heroku

после запуска приложения на heroku (telegram бот без использования спринга, собираемый с помощью maven) где то через минуту работы оно крашится. Я так понимаю что это из за неправильной настройки Procfile.Подскажите как правильно настроить procfile и что вообще приводит к крашу?

Содержимое Procfile:

web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main

содержимое лога после краша:

2019-07-27T14:06:00.083745+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main`

2019-07-27T14:06:02.779856+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.

2019-07-27T14:07:30.671186+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-07-27T14:07:30.755920+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-07-27T14:07:30.547912+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch

2019-07-27T14:07:30.548427+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL

2019-07-27T14:07:30.646846+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137

2019-07-27T14:06:02.783505+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Comment: Вам не помог мой ответ на ваш прошлый вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

Понимаю, что уже поздно, но может кому-то поможет

Содержимое файла `Procfile` должно иметь такой вид:

```
web:    java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/endorsed/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

То есть должен быть указан путь к файлу `webapp-runner.jar`
Если не можете найти его, возможно, он у вас просто не сгенерился, как это было у меня, [тут есть решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1140189/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-webapp-runner-jar-%D0%B2-java-web-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)