# Не могу найти файл webapp-runner.jar в java web приложении

Tags: java, xml, maven, heroku

Я пытаюсь залить свое `java` приложение на хостинг `heroku`. Задеплоить его не удается. Спустя несколько дней поиска я понял, что в файле `Procfile` должен лежать путь к `webapp-runner.jar`. В туториалах этот файл выглядит так:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

Я использую `eclipse` и только недавно конвертировал свой проект в `maven project`. Где может быть этот файл? Или может быть, его нужно откуда-то скачать и установить самостоятельно?

На всякий случай, мой pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>BlagoDari</groupId>
    <artifactId>BlagoDari</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.heroku</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>9.0</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.49</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создаем папку в корне проекта для артефактов, например `artifacts`, которую потом будем загружать (можно вместе со всем проектом) на `heroku.git`.
2. В настройках сборки проекта `maven` указываем имя выходного файла `war`, например `awesomeapp`:

   ```xml
   <build>
       <finalName>awesomeapp</finalName>
       <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
       <plugins>
           . . .
       </plugins>
   </build>
   ```
3. В настройках `maven-dependency-plugin` при добавлении артефакта `webapp-runner` нужно указать для него папку, в которую его надо положить. Указываем `artifacts`:

   ```xml
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.2</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>copy</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                   <artifactItems>
                       <artifactItem>
                           <groupId>com.heroku</groupId>
                           <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                           <version>9.0.31.0</version>
                           <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                       </artifactItem>
                   </artifactItems>
                   <outputDirectory>artifacts</outputDirectory>
               </configuration>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```
4. В настройках `maven-war-plugin` тоже нужно указать выходную папку, куда положить само приложение - туда же в `artifacts`:

   ```xml
   <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.3.0</version>
       <configuration>
           <goal>war:inplace</goal>
           <outputDirectory>artifacts</outputDirectory>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```
5. В корне проекта в файле `Procfile` указываем:

   ```
   web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar artifacts/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT artifacts/awesomeapp.war
   ```
6. Собираем проект из `IDE` с помощью `maven` `package` `goal`. Проверяем наличие этих двух файлов (`webapp-runner.jar` и `awesomeapp.war`) в указанной директории, также проверяем наличие самого `Procfile`. Коммитим эти три файла (можно весь проект целиком) и заливаем на `heroku.git`.

Comment: спасибо, файл появился, но теперь у меня новая ошибка... Когда я пытаюсь деплоить на хероку, мне выдает огромный лог, что тот или иной файл не найден, но вроде главное это  `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project BlagoDari: Compilation failure: Compilation failure`